# Amend django-template if statement to ignore duplicates

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

How do I change the for loop to ignore duplicates `mealtype == 'Entrees'`

I only need it to create 1 `<a href>`

```
{% for menu in menus %}
            {% if menu.mealtype == 'Entrees' %}
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Entrees</a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

full li

```
{% for menu in menus %}
    {% if menu.show_presentation %}
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Entrees</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if menu.show_presentation %}
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sides</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if menu.show_presentation %}
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#tab3" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Mains</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if menu.show_presentation %}
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#tab4" aria-controls="tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Drinks</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if menu.show_presentation %}
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#tab5" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Desserts</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if menu.show_presentation %}
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#tab6" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Specials</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if menu.show_presentation %}
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#tab7" aria-controls="tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Others</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** for view based on comments. Try this:

```
show_presentation_list = []
menus_presentation = []

for menu in menus:
    if menu.mealtype and menu.mealtype not in show_presentation_list:
        show_presentation_list.append(menu.mealtype)
        menus_presentation.append(menu)
```

Also your new template, try this:

```
{% for menu in menus_presentation %}
    <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#tab{{forloop.counter}}" aria-controls="tab{{forloop.counter}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{menu.mealtype}}</a> 
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it to ignore all duplicates. I do have other mealtypes - Entrees, sides, mains, etc. The issue I have now is, even if there is no entry of that particular mealtype, it still show the li.

I tried with
`for menu in menus:
            if menu.mealtype is None:
                menu.show_presentation = False
            elif menu.mealtype == 'Entrees' or 'Sides' or 'Mains' or 'Drinks' or 'Desserts' or 'Specials' or 'Others':
                menu.show_presentation = True
                break`

but doesn't seem to work

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to show the li for each mealtype once (and remove duplicates) or only for Entrees?

Comment: I've just added my full li. Currently is does show each mealtype once and removes duplicates. However I would like the li to not show up at all if it's empty

Comment: Updated the answer with a more re-usuable approach

Comment: Thank mate, works perfectly and much more cleaner than what I had